# Have to make a program that makes a pyramid

Tags: vb.net

I have gotten the basics but how do I input the number of spaces in each row?

This is what Ive done so far:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim var As Char
    Dim numberofsymbols As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("what variable do you want to use to form a pyramid?")
    var = Console.ReadLine

    Console.WriteLine("what number of symbols do you want to start with? (odd number)")
    numberofsymbols = Console.ReadLine()

    'taking numberofsymbols as 5

    Console.Write("   ")
    Console.Write(var)


    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("  ")


    For x = 1 To numberofsymbols - 2
        Console.Write(var)
    Next

    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write(" ")


    For x = 1 To numberofsymbols
        Console.Write(var)
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

The output Im getting is

```
    A

   AAA

  AAAAA
```

Im not checking in my program to see if it is a odd number/one character , how should I go about making this program if the user chooses some random odd number?

I know that ill have to use a repeat until loop for that but then how do I input the number of spaces in a loop like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim var As Char
    Dim numberofsymbols As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("what variable do you want to use to form a pyramid?")
    var = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("what number of symbols do you want to start with? (odd number)")
    numberofsymbols = Console.ReadLine()
    If numberofsymbols Mod 2 = 0 Then numberofsymbols += 1 'to check if the number is even and add '1' to make it odd, you can use 'numberofsymbols -=1' to subtract insead of adding

    Dim spaces As String
    Dim vars As String
    For i = 1 To numberofsymbols Step 2
        spaces = New String(" ", (numberofsymbols - i) / 2)
        vars = New String(var, i)
        Console.WriteLine(spaces + vars)
    Next

    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub
```

And if you want to add an empty line after each row, you can add the following line:

```
        '
        '
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why did you write "new" before string?

Comment: That is called a string constructor (which will create a string of a char repeated n times).. check this out for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And was just going through your program, is that step 2 necessary? If I input the number for the last row as 200, wont it just make a pyramid for 100 numbers?

Comment: Yes, it will do that.. and if by step 2 you mean this line `Console.WriteLine()` you just add that if you want an empty line between after each row.. check this picture if you don't understand: [screenshot](http://s18.postimg.org/smilnpoop/Scr.png)

Comment: "For i = 1 To numberofsymbols Step 2" I meant this step 2

Comment: Oh sorry, I see now.. `Step 2` means: increment i by 2 (1,3,5,7,...) which is the number of symbols in each row.. I hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 0):

```
If NOT NUMBER Mod 2 = 0 Then NUMBER -= 1

'Do your pyramid here
```

Mod 2 will return 0 if its an even number (divided by 2 with no remainder) and will return the remainder otherwise.

Number is the users input.

Comment: I know about MOD but what does NOT do? Is it that logic gate?

Comment: Yes, it would be the same as `If Number Mod 2 <> 0 Then Number -= 1`. An If statement has to be true to proceed with the code within.. Using NOT means it Cannot be true to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim space, maxsymbol, noofsymbol As Integer
        Dim var As Char

        Console.WriteLine("enter char to use")
        var = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine("enter max rows(odd number)")
        maxsymbol = Console.ReadLine



        space = ((maxsymbol - 1) / 2)
        noofsymbol = 1

        Do
            For i = 1 To space
                Console.Write(" ")
            Next

            For x = 1 To noofsymbol
                Console.Write(var)
            Next

            Console.WriteLine()

            space -= 1
            noofsymbol += 2



        Loop Until noofsymbol > maxsymbol



        Console.ReadKey()
```